# How to sort (1,11,12,2,All,Others) to (All,1,2,11,12,Others)?

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a combo box to display my data(varchar) from my DB. The data are always "1,2,3,4, others", when I display the data it sort like this:

```
1
10
11
12
2
3
4
All
Others
```

How to make the drop down look like:

```
All
1
2
3
4
10
11
12
Others
```

OR

In SQL I try to `ORDER BY CAST(priorityNum AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)` after that I add `All` and `Other` into my datatable result. But how to set the `All` and `Others` to be always first and last?

Comment: Show some code.  Tell us what language you're using.

Comment: The question is taged C#

Answer (score 6):

As long as your collection is an `IEnumerable`, you can invoke `OrderBy` with a custom comparer method.
Your comparer would look like this:

```
class myStringComparer: IComparer<string> {
    public int Compare(string a, string b) {
        if (a == b) return 0;
        if (a == "All" || b == "Others") return -1;
        if (a == "Others" || b == "All") return 1;
        return int.Parse(a) - int.Parse(b);
    }
}
```

This, as is, will just throw an exception if unexpected data is found (anything else than "All", "Others", or a number). You may want to add additional logic before attempting the integer parsing.

Now, you can call `.OrderBy(new myStringComparer())` on your list/collection. Note that `OrderBy` will only be available for `IEnumerable` objects (this includes anything you can put on a `foreach` loop, such as arrays, lists, etc).

Comment: You need to switch your "All" || "Others" match. The first should return -1, the other 1 :) Your method sorts Others first, and All last.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you have it stored as a varchar? It should really be an int and this will solve your problem - and be the correct type for your storage

Comment: But that requires the use of two special integers for the All and Others values, or (what I would prefer) some other way of representing these cases.

Comment: Definitely, the need for the special values is quite a good reason for using something other than `int`. Not sure if `varchar` is the best approach, but at the very least it gets the job done. Also, this kind of comments should be posted as _comments_ not as answers: you are not answering the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you could use something like List(T).Sort
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx#Y851

When you make the comparer, check to see if the value is an int, if it is, compare it as normal, 
if not, you know its one of your All/Other cases. You then return a value based on which string you are working on.

That said, if you can just put the ints in the database instead of putting in All and Others and then put them in at runtime it'd make sorting a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need some special comparison method. It should check if the both strings are numbers, then compare using their numeric value. If the first value if All or Others and the second is number, the first value is smaller. If the first is All and the second is Others, the first is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You should either handle (sort) the numbers seperately from the texts and reconstruct the list afterwards. Or store all items which are not sortable in a seperate dictionary, f.e.:

```
All -> 0
Other -> int.MaxVallue
```

Than you walk the unsorted list, seperate the non-number items (via the dictionary or Int.TryParse) from the numbers, sort the numbers in a list and insert the text items from the dictionary afterwards.

Sounds complicated but prepares for changes of those non-number items.

Answer (score 0):

First hand, sort by length and then value, that would solve your problem with 11 coming before 2.

For your two special words, you will need some magic.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by Using CAST at SQL Comment and Add the "All" and "Others" into my datatable in programmatically way.